# TFS: how to differentiate deployed and not yet deployed fixes?

Tags: tfs, bug-tracking

We started using TFS 2013 for tracking bugs. Bugs have very few states: in progress, resolved and done. Let's say we have 10 bugs, we fix 5, deploy to UAT, then we fix another 5. We set all 10 bugs to resolved, but how should the testers know which ones they can test already? Do we have to redraw the process template, or is there a built-in way?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can customize the bug states and add your own states: [Customize the workflow for a work item type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx)
Or you can use the Agile template where the bug has more states by default

Comment: This is a very dysfunctional way to solve this issue and is a reflection of imature processes. Make sure you store environment data separately from your execution flow.

Answer (score 3):

This is managed automatically be TFS. There is a workflow to follow that will provide the result you want:

1. Tester tests and finds bug.
2. Tester creates bug in MTM which fills out the Found In field with the build number
3. Developer creates tasks and associates them with the bug
4. When developer checks in against the task they select "resolves" when they have fixed the bug
5. The next TFS build will detect the "resolved" bug and stamp it with the Resolved In build number.
6. Test manager switches MTM to test new build
7. TFS notifies testers of bugs that can now be validated based on the build currently under test.

Do not reflect the environment that a piece of work is deployed to in the state of the work item in question. This is dysfunctional as it mixes data that should only be related not implicit. Use the workflow above...

If you need to better understand which build includes what you can get that out of TFS in a report. The build stamps the Integrated in' field all the way up the work item hierarchy...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use the Integrated in Build" field of the Bug to track which build fix is resolved in. The field is usually found within the System tab.